# ArcGIS Network Analyst tools are not using historical traffic data to calculate travel time

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, traffic

I have successfully created and built my network dataset with Historical HERE traffic data. However, Network Analyst tools are not using my traffic data to calculate travel time. No matter what time of the day I chose to run the tools, it only came back with the "free-flow" (or the Fallback attribute) travel time.

Here are some screenshots of my ND settings:

[image]

[image]